# CVS filter history by branch

Tags: cvs

I have CVS, and I need to know what was the last commit, and on which files it happened.

The best I've come up with is:
`cvs history -u Arkady -c -D 2018-02-20`

but it prints out ALL files existing in ALL branches.

For example, I have folder `myfolder`.

I have branch BRANCH1 with two files `myfolder/main.cpp` and `myfolder/b1.cpp`

I have branch BRANCH2 with two files `myfolder/main.cpp` and `myfolder/b2.cpp`

If all of those files was modified yesterday, then `cvs history -u Arkady -c -D 2018-02-20` gives me three records with `main`, `b1` and `b2` files.

But I'd like to filter it with branch name.

`-t` and `-r` not helps.

Also I'd like to be able to extract last commit date, to be able to sort by it automatically. But also didn't find generic solution.

Comment: I never had 'history' enabled on my repos (it's optional), but I know that for some other commands CVS was inconsistent and sometimes you could not put a space between `-r` and the branch. e.g. `-r BRANCH1` would not work but `-rBRANCH1` would work. Worth giving a try.

Comment: @Mort, thank you, but it didn't help unfortunately. I've been trying all variants: it looks like one flag sets another to ignore state )